# Error when using gauge tool in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am getting the following error when using the `gauge` in a flexdashboard in RMarkdown:

Quitting from lines 15-18 (example_reprex.Rmd)
Error in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$width) :
CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector
Calls:  ...  -> need_screenshot -> toHTML -> validateCssUnit
Execution halted

Reprex:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

```
   {r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

```
   {r}
gauge(10,
      min = 0,
      max = 20)
```

Session info, FYI:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6



attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2      htmltools_0.5.0     tools_4.0.2         flexdashboard_0.5.2 yaml_2.2.1         
 [6] rmarkdown_2.3       knitr_1.30          jsonlite_1.7.1      xfun_0.17           digest_0.6.25      
[11] rlang_0.4.7         evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: I ran your code and had no issue generating the output. I believe this is a problem with the function  validateCssUnit(x) from shiny. Try adding the argument symbol to gauge.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. Same error. I used the exact code from Yi Hui's page (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/dashboard-components.html#gauges) and got the same errror

Comment: Check out his solution: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1901#issuecomment-699507621

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured it out by simply specifically identifying the first argument. For above example `value = 10` works but just `10` does not.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I actually figured it out by simply specifically identifying the first argument. For above example `value = 10` works but just `10` does not.